# Rails match validates_format_of numbers 1-9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I want to validate a form input so it only takes the numbers 1-9 as input, how can this be achieved

I have this in my model but just cant seem to get the matching correct

validates_format_of :myfield, :with => ??????, :on => :create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

```
 validates :myfield, :inclusion => { :in => 1..9 }
```

or

```
 validates_inclusion_of :myfield, :in => 1..9
```

**EDIT** - I thought `myfield` was an `integer`, but if you have defined it as `string` you need to add the `validates_numericality_of`:

```
validates_numericality_of :myfield, :only_integer => true
validates_inclusion_of :myfield, :in => 1..9
```

Comment: I have tried this however it still allows you to enter things like 3d I need to ensure there are no alphabetic characters at all and that it is only a number

Answer (score 1):

`validates_format_of :myfield, :with => /([^a-zA-Z][1-9]?)/, :on => :create`

Should do just fine if you are using 2.3.x

Note that it is removed after 2.3.8

Comment: I have tried this however it still allows you to enter things like 3d I need to ensure there are no alphabetic characters at all and that it is only a number. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @JonDay i've updated the regex, try again. Can't test right now, but Rubular gets it like that